# When using "azure_rm_deployment" the resourcegroups are creating on specific location "us west"?

Tags: ansible

When using  "azure_rm_deployment" the resourcegroup only creating in us west location. How could i create it in any other location. 
Also when trying to create resources inside that resource group created in central india getting error
Resource group create_or_update failed with status code: 409 and message: Invalid resource group location 'westus'. The Resource group already exists in location 'centralindia'."}

Here is my code

```
- name: Create Azure Deploy
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "myresources" //manualy created in location central india
    parameters:
       location:
          value: Central India
    template:
      $schema: "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"
      contentVersion: "1.0.0.0"
      location: "[variables('location')]"
      deployment-name: "mypx"
      resources:
        - type: "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
          apiVersion: "2015-05-01-preview"
          name: "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]"
          location: "[parameters('location')]"
          properties:
            addressSpace:
              addressPrefixes:
                - "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
            subnets:
              - name: "[variables('subnetName')]"
                properties:
                  addressPrefix: "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

See in the [Ansible documentation of the azure_rm_deployment module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_deployment_module.html): this module has a `location` parameter you can use.

So your task would begin with this:

```
- name: Create Azure Deploy
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "myresources" //manualy created in location central india
    location: your-desired-location
```

and this block can be omitted:

```
    parameters:
       location:
          value: Central India
```